# Putting java script into a form as a present value

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a restaurant choosing program. It takes an array of strings, uses the random function and then displays the choice into a form text box.

I can not get it to work. I have been working at it for 4 hours. The JavaScript works fine but I just can't get it to display in the text box.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Generate Restaurant</button>


    <script>
    var food = ["Molinas", "Sonic", "Subway", "McDonalds", "Taco Bell","Pasanos", "Lone Star Eatery", "Chicken Express"];


    function myFunction() {
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 0);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = food[x];
    }


    </script>

    <form>
    <input id="demo" type="text">
    </form>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`

Answer (score -1):

Would this be a better way of doing it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
var food = ["Molinas", "Sonic", "Subway", "McDonalds", "Taco Bell", "Pasanos", "Lone Star Eatery", "Chicken Express"];


function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 0);
    return food[x];
}


</script>

<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter name: <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```